# Error: EACCES: permission denied NPM Ubuntu Server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, npm

I am running an Ubuntu EC2 server and followed the [tutorial provided by AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/setting-up-node-on-ec2-instance.html) to install `nvm` and `node`, but when I try to run `npm install`, I'm thrown an error:

```
Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/var/www/app'
Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
```

The standard procedure with an EC2 Ubuntu service appears to only provide a `ubuntu` user with `sudo` privileges and no access to `root` so I tried to run `sudo npm install`, but I receive `sudo: npm: command not found`. The reason why I believe this is happening is because nvm is located at `/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v6.12.3/bin/node`, which `root` might not have access to?

Is it possible to point `root` to the this directory location for this command or is there a different solution?

Comment: as `sudo` the command is probably not in your path. You have a few options. You can pass the whole path of the command, you can give ubuntu permission to `/var/www/app` or you can set up a configuration that uses a folder you already own. Unless this is production I recommend the last one.

Comment: can you explain your recommended approach in detail? I'm not sure I follow. I don't have the best experience dealing with user versus root privileges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting that error because you do not have write permission for your user on that /var/www/app.

You can follow the answer here to give permissions to that folder.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/749697/how-do-i-give-myself-access-to-var-www-to-create-and-edit-files-and-folders-in

You are getting the error about npm not being installed when you use sudo because it is not installed for the admin user. I would avoid installing node and npm through sudo though. Just go with changing the folder permissions.

Comment: I'm glad to help.